# How do I distribute a value between numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, math, statistics, probability

I am creating a bias dice rolling simulator I want the user to:

1.Input the number they would like to change the prob of

2.Input the prob (in decimal form)

Then I would like my program to distribute the remainder between the other values, this is my first post - let me know if any other info is needed

My Code:

```
choice = int(input('Which number would you like to change to the probability of?:  '))

prob = int(input('Probability: '))

probs = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

probs[choice] = prob
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
choice = 2
prob = 20

choices = []
for i in range(6):
    if i == choice:
        choices.append(prob)
    else:
        choices.append((100 - prob) / 5)
print(choices)
```

output:

```
[16.0, 16.0, 20, 16.0, 16.0, 16.0]
```

---

To compute the probability, we divide the remainder (`100 - prob`) by the number of faces to share the remainder with (`5`).

We loop for each side of the die. If it is the face to be modified, we set it to `prob`, otherwise we set it to one-fifth of the remainder.

Answer (score -2):

```py
filler_list = []
while sum(filler_list) < variable_to_distribute:
    for filler_index in range(list_length):
        if len(filler_list) < list_length:
            if sum(filler_list) < variable_to_distribute:
                filler_list.append(1)
            else:
                filler_list.append(0)
        elif sum(filler_list) < variable_to_distribute:
            filler_list[filler_index] += 1
if sum(filler_list) != variable_to_distribute:
    raise ErrorC(f"The remainder {variable_to_distribute} wasn't distributed correctly")
```

Comment: Just with int numbers